# Insertar registros de una tabla con clave compuesta

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo tres tablas tblmateriaprima , tblfacturacompra y tblfacturacompramateriaprima(tabla que tiene la clave compuesta)
Quiero que mi formulario funcione y que se guarden los registros correspondientes en cada tabla.
En las dos tablas normales se guardan los registros correctamente pero en la tabla tblfacturacompramateriaprima(tabla que tiene la clave compuesta) no se guarda nada y me suelta este error

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventario`.`tblfacturacompramateriaprima`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_facturacompra_materiaprima_tbl_facturacompra1` FOREIGN KEY (`factura_compra`) REFERENCES `tblfacturacompra` (`numero`) ON DELETE)
```

Lo que entiendo es que me muestra ese error porque el codigo que se debe guardar en la tabla de clave compuesta ,es autoincremental en las otras, entonces por eso no se guarda como se guardaría normal en un formulario porque no tengo ningún input que me registre dicho dato y que lo pueda traer por metodo post  pero no se como solucionar eso.  ayudenme porfavor ! Este es mi codigo en donde guardo los datos que recogo del formulario.

```
<?php
include ("../includes/conexion.php");

$proveedor = $_POST["proveedor"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$codigo= $_POST["codigo"];
$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$unidad_medida=  $_POST["unidad_medida"]; 
$unidades_disponibles = $_POST["cantidad"];
$fecha_vencimiento= $_POST["fecha_vencimiento"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"]; 
 
$guardar_compra = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompra(proveedor,forma_pago,fecha) 
VALUES ('$proveedor','$forma_pago','$fecha')";

$guardar_compra_materia = "INSERT INTO tblfacturacompramateriaprima(materia_prima,cantidad,precio_unitario)
VALUES ('$codigo' , '$unidades_disponibles' , '$precio_unitario' )";

$guardar_materia_prima = "INSERT INTO tblmateriaprima(codigo,nombre,unidad_medida,unidades_disponibles,fecha_vencimiento) 
VALUES ('$codigo','$nombre','$unidad_medida','$unidades_disponibles','$fecha_vencimiento')";

if ($conexion->query( $guardar_compra ) && $conexion->query($guardar_materia_prima) && $conexion->query($guardar_compra_materia) ) {

echo "si";
}else {

    echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";   
}

include ("../includes/desconexion.php");
?>
```

Aqui Mostraré pantallazos de la base de datos y las tablas para quienes me lo han pedido y porfavor me ayuden a solucionar el error:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblfacturacompra` (
  `numero` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `proveedor` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `forma_pago` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numero`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_facturacompra_tbl_formapago1_idx` (`forma_pago`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_facturacompra_tbl_proveedor1_idx` (`proveedor`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_facturacompra_tbl_formapago1` FOREIGN KEY (`forma_pago`) REFERENCES `tblformapago` (`codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_facturacompra_tbl_proveedor1` FOREIGN KEY (`proveedor`) REFERENCES `tblproveedor` (`nit`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


--
-- Table structure for table `tblfacturacompramateriaprima`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblfacturacompramateriaprima`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tblfacturacompramateriaprima` (
  `materia_prima` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `factura_compra` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `precio_unitario` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`materia_prima`,`factura_compra`),
  KEY `fk_tbl_facturacompra_materiaprima_tbl_facturacompra1_idx` (`factura_compra`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_facturacompra_materiaprima_tbl_facturacompra1` FOREIGN KEY (`factura_compra`) REFERENCES `tblfacturacompra` (`numero`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_facturacompra_materiaprima_tbl_materiaprima1` FOREIGN KEY (`materia_prima`) REFERENCES `tblmateriaprima` (`codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


--
-- Table structure for table `tblfacturaventa`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tblfacturaventa`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tblfacturaventa` (
  `numero` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cliente` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `forma_pago` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numero`),
  KEY `fk_tblfacturaventa_tbl_formapago1_idx` (`forma_pago`),
  KEY `fk_tblfacturaventa_tbl_clientes1_idx` (`cliente`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblfacturaventa_tbl_clientes1` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente`) REFERENCES `tbl_cliente` (`documento`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblfacturaventa_tbl_formapago1` FOREIGN KEY (`forma_pago`) REFERENCES `tblformapago` (`codigo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE
```

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con clave compuesta? ¿Foreign Key?

Comment: Hola, tendrías que ejecutar primero los `INSERT` en `tblfacturacompra` y en  `tblmateriaprima`, luego recuperar los dos nuevos `ID` que se crearon en ellas con [`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) y usar esos dos valores para insertarlos en `tblfacturacompramateriaprima`. Aunque por el mensaje de error no me queda claro que tus restricciones de tabla estén bien. Propongo que hagas un  `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;` para tus tres tablas, copies y pegues el resultado de c/u en la pregunta para entender cómo tienes montado el modelo de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas tardes lo que entiendo de tu problema es que tienes 3 tablas las cuales son tblmateriaprima , tblfacturacompra y tblfacturacompramateriaprima, per resulta que la tabla tblfacturacompramateriaprima colocaste una llave Foreign Key de alguna de las tablas anteriores, entonces cuando tu quieres meter un datos en esa tabla tienes que colocar el id de algún registro que tienes en tu tabla que colocaste como FK(Foreign Key).

De favor si nos apoyas colocando capturas de pantalla de los atributos que colocaste en cada una de tus tablas. Para poder obtener los atributos de tus tablas corre el siguiente script el cual te enlista los atributos que tienes en cada una de tus tablas y te proporciona información del tipo de dato que está manejando cada atributo.

> Ejemplo

```
DESC tblfacturacompra;
```

Así lo vas a hacer con cada una de tus tablas y a esos resultados les tomas captura de pantalla para que nos las compartas.